# xaml wpf is it possible to add a dollar sign for a each entry in a dataGrid column

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

here is my dataGrid

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding name}" Width="Auto"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="income" Binding="{Binding income}" Width="*"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="age" Binding="{Binding age}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

and in code behind I add a row by
            `dataGrid1.Items.Add(new person{ name = _name, income = _income, age= _age});`

Income is a double, so I cant just do `_income = "$" + _income`. Is there any way to set it in xaml so that it will add a $ sign to all entry in income column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard .NET format strings for binding

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="income" Binding="{Binding Path=income, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" Width="*"/>
```